# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sql' PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I try to run the following code and I get an error ( I removed the part with credentials and database details):

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sql'**

Traceback:

File "/usr/lib/python_udf/95171f0c341a99142582d8d66eb74de9c14d6116523ffe10b14270e1d165f7ea/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script    exec(code, module.__dict__)
    File "/home/udf/100918851370726/streamlit_app.py", line 181, in 
    edtr = StrmltEditor(table_name=p_table_name, connection_parameters=p_connection_parameters)File "/home/udf/100918851370726/streamlit_app.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.read_structure(table=self.table_name) File "/home/udf/100918851370726/streamlit_app.py", line 175, in read_structure
    df_sql = self.session.sql(sql.format(table_name = table))

````
import string
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import os, sys
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
import inspect as ins
p_connection_parameters = {
    "account": p_account,
    "user": p_user,
    "password": p_password,
    "role": p_role,
    "warehouse": p_warehouse,
    "database": p_database,
    "schema": p_schema,
    #"token": token,
    #"authenticator":'externalbrowser',
    "client_session_keep_alive": True
}

`class StrmltEditor:`

    `def __init__(self, connection_parameters, table_name):
        self.connection_parameters = connection_parameters
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.session = None
        self.df_structure = None
        self.df_results = None
        self.df_results_edited = None
        self.structure = {}
        self.columns = []

        self.create_session()
        self.read_structure(table=self.table_name)
        self.build_structure()
        self.read_table(table=self.table_name, columns=', '.join(self.columns))


        st.title(self.table_name + ' editor :D')
        with st.form("editor"):
            self.df_results_edited = st.data_editor(self.df_results, column_config=self.structure, hide_index=True, key="ops", num_rows = "dynamic")
            submit_button = st.form_submit_button("Write")
            reload_button = st.form_submit_button("Reload")
        if submit_button:
            # DWH_ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL autoincrement, -- number
            # DWH_SOURCE_KEY VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, --  source_value_name lower
            # DWH_CR_LOAD_ID NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, --  random number
            # DWH_CR_JOB VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'MANUAL', -- 'streamlit'
            # DWH_CR_DATE DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE(), -- 'current_date'
            today = date.today()
            self.df_results_edited['DWH_ID'] = range(1, 1 + len(self.df_results_edited))
            self.df_results_edited['DWH_SOURCE_KEY'] = self.df_results_edited['SOURCE_VALUE_NAME'].str.lower()
            self.df_results_edited['DWH_CR_LOAD_ID'] = int(today.strftime('%m%d%Y'))
            self.df_results_edited['DWH_CR_JOB'] = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
            self.df_results_edited['DWH_CR_DATE'] = date.today()
            self.df_results_edited['SOURCE_VALUE_NAME'] = self.df_results_edited['SOURCE_VALUE_NAME'].str.upper()
            tmp = self.session.create_dataframe(self.df_results_edited)
            tmp.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table(self.table_name)
            #st.expander("Edited dataset", expanded=True).dataframe(self.df_results_edited, use_container_width=True)
        if reload_button:
            st.experimental_rerun()

        print(1)
        pass

    def read_data(self, table):
        pass

    def get_structure(self):
        if len(self.structure)>0:
            return self.structure
        else:
            return None
    def convert_column_name(self, col_name):
        return string.capwords(col_name.replace('_', ' ')).replace('Dwh ', '')

    def build_structure(self):
        if len(self.df_structure)>0:
            for i, r in self.df_structure.iterrows():
                if r.COLUMN_NAME == 'DWH_SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME':
                    self.structure.update({r.COLUMN_NAME: st.column_config.SelectboxColumn(self.convert_column_name(r.COLUMN_NAME), help="Select source System Name", required =True, width="medium", options=["CTMS", "CITELN"])})
                    self.columns.append(r.COLUMN_NAME)
                if r.COLUMN_NAME == 'SOURCE_VALUE_NAME':
                    self.structure.update({r.COLUMN_NAME : st.column_config.TextColumn(self.convert_column_name(r.COLUMN_NAME),help="Valid source value name should contain only BIG or small letters and spaces", default='PROVIDE VALID SOURCE VALUE NAME', required =True,max_chars=500,validate="^[a-zA-Z\s]+$")})
                    self.columns.append(r.COLUMN_NAME)
                if r.COLUMN_NAME == 'MEDDRA_CODE':
                    self.structure.update({r.COLUMN_NAME : st.column_config.NumberColumn(self.convert_column_name(r.COLUMN_NAME),step=1)})
                    self.columns.append(r.COLUMN_NAME)
                if r.COLUMN_NAME == 'ICD_10_CATEGORY_CODE':
                    self.structure.update({r.COLUMN_NAME : st.column_config.TextColumn(self.convert_column_name(r.COLUMN_NAME),max_chars=500,validate="^[A-Z](1)[0-9]+$")})
                    self.columns.append(r.COLUMN_NAME)
                if r.DATA_TYPE == 'TEXT' and r.COLUMN_NAME not in ['DWH_SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME', 'SOURCE_VALUE_NAME', 'MEDDRA_CODE', 'ICD_10_CATEGORY_CODE']:
                    self.structure.update({r.COLUMN_NAME : self.convert_column_name(r.COLUMN_NAME)})
                    self.columns.append(r.COLUMN_NAME)

        else:
            print('Missing data from information schema')

    def get_df_structure(self):
        return self.df_structure
    def create_session(self):
        try:
            self.session = Session.builder.configs(self.connection_parameters).create()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Issue on:', ins.currentframe(), e)

    def read_table(self, table, columns):
        sql = """
        SELECT {columns}
        FROM {table_name}
        """.format(table_name = table, columns = columns)
        df_sql = self.session.sql(sql)

        self.df_results = pd.DataFrame(df_sql.toPandas())


    def read_structure(self, table):
        sql = """
        SELECT TABLE_CATALOG,
        TABLE_SCHEMA,
        TABLE_NAME,
        COLUMN_NAME,
        ORDINAL_POSITION,
        COLUMN_DEFAULT,
        IS_NULLABLE,
        DATA_TYPE,
        CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
        CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH,
        NUMERIC_PRECISION,
        NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX,
        NUMERIC_SCALE,
        DATETIME_PRECISION,
        INTERVAL_TYPE,
        INTERVAL_PRECISION,
        CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG,
        CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA,
        CHARACTER_SET_NAME,
        COLLATION_CATALOG,
        COLLATION_SCHEMA,
        COLLATION_NAME,
        DOMAIN_CATALOG,
        DOMAIN_SCHEMA,
        DOMAIN_NAME,
        UDT_CATALOG,
        UDT_SCHEMA,
        UDT_NAME,
        SCOPE_CATALOG,
        SCOPE_SCHEMA,
        SCOPE_NAME,
        MAXIMUM_CARDINALITY,
        DTD_IDENTIFIER,
        IS_SELF_REFERENCING,
        IS_IDENTITY,
        IDENTITY_GENERATION,
        IDENTITY_START,
        IDENTITY_INCREMENT,
        IDENTITY_MAXIMUM,
        IDENTITY_MINIMUM,
        IDENTITY_CYCLE,
        "COMMENT" FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA."COLUMNS" WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{table_name}'  AND ((COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL AND COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE 'DWH%') OR COLUMN_NAME = 'DWH_SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME') ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
        """
        df_sql = self.session.sql(sql.format(table_name = table))

        self.df_structure = df_sql.toPandas()


edtr = StrmltEditor(table_name=p_table_name, connection_parameters=p_connection_parameters)
#tmp = read_structure(p_table_name)
#session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
#table = session.table(p_table_name)
#table = table.limit(100)
#df = table.collect()
#st.write(st.session_state.ops)```
````